# Issues converting dtype i4 to dtype s4

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

So i have an array that is (10,3) with type of i4. Im looking to convert the data to 3 different string arrays, but i'm having issues with the 2d version of the array.

```
import numpy
xyz = (100.0*numpy.random.random((10,3))).astype("i4")
A = xyz[:,0:3].view("S12") #works fine
B = xyz[:,0:2].view("S8") #fails
C = xyz[:,0:1].view("S4") #works fine

D = xyz[0,0:2].view("S8") #works fine using only 1 element instead of whole array
```

Why is it not possible for me to convert to the general form:

```
xyz[:,0:dim].view("S%d"%(4*dim))
```

regardless of the dim chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xyz[:,:2].copy().view('S8')
```

works.

With `[:,:2]` you are viewing 2 numbers (4 byte blocks), skipping 1, viewing the next 2 etc.  That's a view, not a copy, because strides and shape can handle that without changing the underlying data.

But if you try to view the same thing in 8 bytes blocks, strides can't handle it.  It requires viewing 1 block, skipping 1/2 block, etc.

By making a copy, those 8 byte blocks are contiguous, and can be viewed as a unit.

`numpy.array(xyz[:,0:2].tostring())` is effectively a copy - writing the data (just the `:2` columns) to a bytestring, and recreating an array.

Comment: So the [:,:3] and [:,:1] work because its viewing a whole block, or viewing 1 and skipping 2? No weird half-blocks involved?

Answer (score 0):

So i've done some experimenting and it looks like i've found something that consistently works:

```
numpy.array(xyz[:,0:2].tostring()).view("10S8").reshape(10,1)
```

Im not super pumped to be using it since its so odd looking, but it works so whatever i guess. If anyone has a better answer let me know.